# Retrieving original image from thumbnails in a LongListMultiSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit, longlistselector

i am using a LongListMultiSelector to display all the images from the Media Library. To prevent running out of memory , i used the following ode to display thumbnails..
    this.DataContext = this;

```
        var Pictures = ml.Pictures;
        foreach (var item in Pictures)
        {
            ListOfImages.Add(PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(item.GetThumbnail()));
            name.Add(item.Name);

        }
```

ListOfImages is the list binded to the LongList.

i have attached the OnSelectionChanged event handler to determine the selected images by the user , however i only get the thumbnails from their , how do i get the original image from it ??i want to store the original image to the isolated storage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have identifier for selected image (the name for example), then you can search for the actual image from `MediaLibrary` by name :

```
var picture = media.Pictures
                   .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Contains("the_name.jpg"));

if (picture != null)
{
    // Picture found
    var originalImage = picture.GetImage();
    // do something with original image
}
```